# Continually adding path to sys.path

Tags: python

I have inherited quite a bit of python code and all over it is the following snippet which adds the file path of the parent directory to the system path.

```
from os.path import join, dirname
sys.path.insert(0, join(dirname(sys.argv[0]), "..\\"))
from utilities import find, execute
```

My understanding of this is that it adds a path to the search path. Which during the running of a program adds numerous pathsto the search path and presumably make it slower. As each file adds it's own parent directory.

I prefer the syntax

```
from scm_tools.general.utilities import find, execute
```

because this is easier to understand and far less code. This might have implications if I am moving the code around but it's all in a single package.

Am I right in assuming that inside a package that the latter syntax is the more pythonic way of doing things ?

or does it not really matter as under the hood python is doing some magic ?

Comment: your two examples are not equivelent ... with python 2.7 it introduced relative imports ...  I think you would do something like `from ..utilities import find,execute`  ... but yeah generally speaking it is bad form to edit the path from inside your program (every rule has exceptions however)

Comment: This is an awful pattern. If the code you mention is all in the same package (`scm_tools`?), then your preferred syntax is much better.

Comment: or just use your actual system ENVIRNOMENT to set the path or pythonpath to the desired values (or even your IDE typically)

Comment: Another problem with that pattern is that modules inside `scm_tools` could mask other top level modules. Suppose somebody creates `scm_tools/xml.py` - a perfectly reasonable thing to do. Then you spend a day wondering why your deployments are crashing on `import xml.etree.ElementTree`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use relative imports when you can:

`from ..utilities import find, execute`

This requires that you stay within the module space, which means each directory you traverse requires an `__init__.py` file.

There are cases where this breaks down, for example if your tests directory isn't inside the module structure. In these cases you need to edit the path, but you shouldn't edit the path blindly like the above example.

Either add to the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable before you code starts so you can always reference the root of the directory or only add paths that aren't already in the `sys.path` and try avoiding adding anything but module roots.

The `PYTHONPATH` change is a bit risky for code you wish to distribute. It's easy to have a change in `PYTHONPATH` you can't control or for you to not define that addition in a way that transfers to distributed code. It also adds an annoying module requirement that other's have to deal with -- so reserve this for adding whole swaths of modules that you want to include, like custom site-package directories. It's *almost* always better to use virtualenv for such situations.

If you do need to change a `sys.path` inside code you should try to at least avoid clobbering it all over the place or you'll have a headache trying to fix it when it goes awry. To avoid this try to only add root module paths so you can always import in a `root.submodule.desiredmodule` pattern. Additionally check if a path is already present before you insert it into `sys.path` to avoid very long `sys.path`s. In my test directories I oftentimes have an importable file that fixes the `sys.path` to the root of the directory structures I am testing:

```
# Add parent import capabilities
parentdir = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..'))
if parentdir not in sys.path:
    sys.path.insert(0, parentdir)
```